# SyncFusion calendar does not appear

Tags: flutter, dart, syncfusion, syncfusion-calendar

I watched a video about Syncfusion Calendar, and while it worked as an independent widget, it kind of never works when we tried implementing it for our application. It yields us with either a blank screen or the Appbar and the FloatingActionButton appearing only. How can I make it visible?

Mind the fact that we are not making this widget the main page and has to be accessible from the dashboard itself.

```
class CalendarTeacherPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const CalendarTeacherPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _CalendarTeacherPageState createState() => _CalendarTeacherPageState();
}

class _CalendarTeacherPageState extends State<CalendarTeacherPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(child: const CalendarWidget()),
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Calendar'),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        child: const Icon(Icons.add, color: Colors.white),
        backgroundColor: Colors.red,
        onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).push(
          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const EventEditingPage()),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This one is for our CalendarWidget, which we believe to be holding the errors.

```
class CalendarWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const CalendarWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final events = Provider.of<EventProvider>(context).events;

    return SfCalendar(
      view: CalendarView.schedule,
      dataSource: EventDataSource(events),
      initialSelectedDate: DateTime.now(),
      cellBorderColor: Colors.transparent,
      onLongPress: (details) {
        final provider = Provider.of<EventProvider>(context, listen: true);

        provider.setDate(details.date!);
        showModalBottomSheet(
          context: context,
          builder: (context) => const TasksWidget(),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Migrating this code from the SfCalendar acting as the main widget to it being part of our dashboard has proven difficult, and I just know that the issue is in the SfCalendar and where I am placing it. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the code snippet, we have checked the mentioned issue “**Calendar not rendering**” and it was working fine as expected from our end. We have attached the code snippet for the same.

**Code snippet:**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:syncfusion_flutter_calendar/calendar.dart';

void main() {
  return runApp(const Calendar());
}

class Calendar extends StatefulWidget {
  const Calendar({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  CalendarState createState() =>
      CalendarState();
}

class CalendarState
    extends State<Calendar> {



  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
          floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
            child: const Icon(Icons.add),
            onPressed: () {},
          ),
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: const Text('text'),
          ),
          body: const CalendarPage()),
    );
  }
}

class CalendarPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const CalendarPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return SfCalendar();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I realized that I was missing something in the application, and it was the ChangeNotifier. By changing the code into this...

```
class CalendarTeacher extends StatefulWidget {
  const CalendarTeacher({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<CalendarTeacher> createState() => _CalendarTeacher();
}

class _CalendarTeacher extends State<CalendarTeacher> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => ChangeNotifierProvider(
        create: (context) => EventProvider(),
        child: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: const Text("Calendar"),
            centerTitle: true,
          ),
          body: CalendarWidget(),
          floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
            child: Icon(Icons.add, color: Colors.white),
            backgroundColor: Colors.red,
            onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).push(
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const EventEditingPage()),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );
}
```

I completely forgot about the EventProvider in a sense, so all is good now!